# Hide function in wizard form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do something with wizard form,in step 1 user can choose a radio button to hide or show content on step 2.
But I can't do it,the content on step 2 will not effect by what I choose in step1.
In order to more easy understand my question,I have do what I want in step3.
conclusion what I want:user choose hide radio button in step 1, the content on step 2 will hide.

```js
"use strict";
function scroll_to_class(element_class, removed_height) {
 var scroll_to = $(element_class).offset().top - removed_height;
 if($(window).scrollTop() != scroll_to) {
  $('.form-wizard').stop().animate({scrollTop: scroll_to}, 0);
 }
}

function bar_progress(progress_line_object, direction) {
 var number_of_steps = progress_line_object.data('number-of-steps');
 var now_value = progress_line_object.data('now-value');
 var new_value = 0;
 if(direction == 'right') {
  new_value = now_value + ( 100 / number_of_steps );
 }
 else if(direction == 'left') {
  new_value = now_value - ( 100 / number_of_steps );
 }
 progress_line_object.attr('style', 'width: ' + new_value + '%;').data('now-value', new_value);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
    /*
        Form
    */
    $('.form-wizard fieldset:first').fadeIn('slow');
    
    $('.form-wizard .required').on('focus', function() {
     $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    });
    
    // next step
    $('.form-wizard .btn-next').on('click', function() {
     var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
     var next_step = true;
     // navigation steps / progress steps
     var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-step.active');
     var progress_line = $(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-progress-line');
     
     // fields validation
     parent_fieldset.find('.required').each(function() {
      if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
       $(this).addClass('input-error');
       next_step = false;
      }
      else {
       $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }
     });
     // fields validation
     
     if( next_step ) {
      parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
       // change icons
       current_active_step.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active');
       // progress bar
       bar_progress(progress_line, 'right');
       // show next step
       $(this).next().fadeIn();
       // scroll window to beginning of the form
       scroll_to_class( $('.form-wizard'), 20 );
      });
     }
     
    });
    
    // previous step
    $('.form-wizard .btn-previous').on('click', function() {
     // navigation steps / progress steps
     var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-step.active');
     var progress_line = $(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-progress-line');
     
     $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function() {
      // change icons
      current_active_step.removeClass('active').prev().removeClass('activated').addClass('active');
      // progress bar
      bar_progress(progress_line, 'left');
      // show previous step
      $(this).prev().fadeIn();
      // scroll window to beginning of the form
   scroll_to_class( $('.form-wizard'), 20 );
     });
    });
    
    // submit
    $('.form-wizard').on('submit', function(e) {
     
     // fields validation
     $(this).find('.required').each(function() {
      if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).addClass('input-error');
      }
      else {
       $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }
     });
     // fields validation
     
    });
    
    
});





// image uploader scripts 

var $dropzone = $('.image_picker'),
    $droptarget = $('.drop_target'),
    $dropinput = $('#inputFile'),
    $dropimg = $('.image_preview'),
    $remover = $('[data-action="remove_current_image"]');

$dropzone.on('dragover', function() {
  $droptarget.addClass('dropping');
  return false;
});

$dropzone.on('dragend dragleave', function() {
  $droptarget.removeClass('dropping');
  return false;
});

$dropzone.on('drop', function(e) {
  $droptarget.removeClass('dropping');
  $droptarget.addClass('dropped');
  $remover.removeClass('disabled');
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0],
      reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    $dropimg.css('background-image', 'url(' + event.target.result + ')');
  };
  
  console.log(file);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  return false;
});

$dropinput.change(function(e) {
  $droptarget.addClass('dropped');
  $remover.removeClass('disabled');
  $('.image_title input').val('');
  
  var file = $dropinput.get(0).files[0],
      reader = new FileReader();
  
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    $dropimg.css('background-image', 'url(' + event.target.result + ')');
  }
  
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

$remover.on('click', function() {
  $dropimg.css('background-image', '');
  $droptarget.removeClass('dropped');
  $remover.addClass('disabled');
  $('.image_title input').val('');
});

$('.image_title input').blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $droptarget.removeClass('dropped');
  }
});

// image uploader scripts
```

```css
.form-box {
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 
 background: rgb(234,88,4); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(234,88,4,1) 0%, rgba(234,40,3,1) 51%, rgba(234,88,4,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(234,88,4,1) 0%,rgba(234,40,3,1) 51%,rgba(234,88,4,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(234,88,4,1) 0%,rgba(234,40,3,1) 51%,rgba(234,88,4,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ea5804', endColorstr='#ea5804',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.form-wizard {
 padding: 25px; 
 background: #fff;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 3px #777;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #888;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
 
.form-wizard strong { font-weight: 500; }

.form-wizard a, .form-wizard a:hover, .form-wizard a:focus {
 color: #ea2803;
 text-decoration: none;
    -o-transition: all .3s; -moz-transition: all .3s; -webkit-transition: all .3s; -ms-transition: all .3s; transition: all .3s;
}

.form-wizard h1, .form-wizard h2 {
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.form-wizard h3 {
 font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #ea2803;
    line-height: 30px;
 margin-top: 0; 
 margin-bottom: 5px; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.form-wizard h4 {
 float:left;
 font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #ea2803;
    line-height: 26px;
 width:100%;
}
.form-wizard h4  span{
 float:right;
 font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.form-wizard table tr th{font-weight:normal;}

.form-wizard img { max-width: 100%; }

.form-wizard ::-moz-selection { background: #ea2803; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
.form-wizard ::selection { background: #ea2803; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }


.form-control {
 height: 44px;
 width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 44px;
    color: #888;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;
    -o-transition: all .3s; -moz-transition: all .3s; -webkit-transition: all .3s; -ms-transition: all .3s; transition: all .3s;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"], .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"], .radio input[type="radio"], .radio-inline input[type="radio"] {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 9px;
 margin-left: -20px;
}

.form-control option:hover, .form-control option:checked  {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #ea2803 inset;
}

.form-control:focus {
 outline: 0;
 background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;
}

.form-control:-moz-placeholder { color: #888; }
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #888; }
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #888; }

.form-wizard label { font-weight: 300; }
.form-wizard label span { color:#ea2803; }


.form-wizard .btn {
 min-width: 105px;
 height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;
    -o-transition: all .3s; -moz-transition: all .3s; -webkit-transition: all .3s; -ms-transition: all .3s; transition: all .3s;
}

.form-wizard .btn:hover {
 background:#f34727; 
 color: #fff; 
 }
.form-wizard .btn:active { 
 outline: 0; 
 background:#f34727; 
 color: #fff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: none; 
 -webkit-box-shadow: none; 
 box-shadow: none; 
 }
.form-wizard .btn:focus,
.form-wizard .btn:active:focus,
.form-wizard .btn.active:focus { 
 outline: 0; 
 background:#f34727; 
 color: #fff; 
}

.form-wizard .btn.btn-next,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-next:focus,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-next:active:focus, 
.form-wizard .btn.btn-next.active:focus { 
background: #ea2803; 
}

.form-wizard .btn.btn-submit,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-submit:focus,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-submit:active:focus, 
.form-wizard .btn.btn-submit.active:focus { 
background: #ea2803; 
}

.form-wizard .btn.btn-previous,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-previous:focus,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-previous:active:focus, 
.form-wizard .btn.btn-previous.active:focus { 
background: #bbb;
}

.form-wizard .success h3{
 color: #4F8A10;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px auto !important;
}
.form-wizard .success .success-icon {
 color: #4F8A10;
 font-size: 100px;
 border: 5px solid #4F8A10;
 border-radius: 100px;
 text-align: center !important;
 width: 110px;
 margin: 25px auto;
}
.form-wizard .progress-bar {
 background-color: #ea2803;
}

.form-wizard-steps{ 
 margin:auto; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative; 
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.form-wizard-step{
 padding-top:10px !important;
 border:2px solid #fff;
 background:#ccc;
 -ms-transform: skewX(-30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-30deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(-30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
.form-wizard-step.active{
 background:#ea2803;
}
.form-wizard-step.activated{
 background:#ea2803;
}
.form-wizard-progress { 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 36px;
 left: 0; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 0px; 
 background: #ea2803;
}
.form-wizard-progress-line { 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 height: 0px; 
 background: #ea2803; 
}

.form-wizard-tolal-steps-3 .form-wizard-step { 
 position: relative;
 float: left; 
 width: 33.33%; 
 padding: 0 5px; 
}
.form-wizard-tolal-steps-4 .form-wizard-step { 
 position: relative; 
 float: left; 
 width: 25%; 
 padding: 0 5px; 
}
.form-wizard-tolal-steps-5 .form-wizard-step { 
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 padding: 0 5px;
}

.form-wizard-step-icon {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 40px; 
 height: 40px; 
 margin-top: 4px; 
 background: #ddd;
 font-size: 16px; 
 color: #777; 
 line-height: 40px;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
 border-radius: 50%;
 -ms-transform: skewX(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(30deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
.form-wizard-step.activated .form-wizard-step-icon {
 background: #ea2803; 
 border: 1px solid #fff; 
 color: #fff; 
 line-height: 38px;
}
.form-wizard-step.active .form-wizard-step-icon {
 background: #fff; 
 border: 1px solid #fff; 
 color: #ea2803; 
 line-height: 38px;
}

.form-wizard-step p { 
 color: #fff;
 -ms-transform: skewX(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(30deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
.form-wizard-step.activated p { color: #fff; }
.form-wizard-step.active p { color: #fff; }

.form-wizard fieldset { 
 display: none; 
 text-align: left; 
 border:0px !important
}

.form-wizard-buttons { text-align: right; }

.form-wizard .input-error { border-color: #ea2803;}

/** image uploader **/
.image-upload a[data-action] {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}
.image-upload a[data-action] i {
  width: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
}
.image-upload a[data-action]:hover {
  color: #ea2803;
}
.image-upload a[data-action].disabled {
  opacity: 0.35;
  cursor: default;
}
.image-upload a[data-action].disabled:hover {
  color: #555;
}
.settings_wrap{
 margin-top:20px;
}
.image_picker .settings_wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.image_picker .settings_wrap .drop_target,
.image_picker .settings_wrap .settings_actions {
  float: left;
}
.image_picker .settings_wrap .drop_target {
  margin-right: 18px;
}
.image_picker .settings_wrap .settings_actions {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.settings_actions.vertical a {
  display: block;
}
.drop_target {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.2s;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 8px solid #E0E0E0;
}
.drop_target input[type="file"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.drop_target::before {
 content: 'Drop Hear';
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 220px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 transition: color 0.2s;
}
.drop_target:hover,
.drop_target.dropping {
  background: #f80;
  border-top-color: #cc6d00;
}
.drop_target:hover:before,
.drop_target.dropping:before {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.drop_target .image_preview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>

</head>

<body>
<style>
#cuss:not(:checked) ~ #con {
      display: none;
      }
   
#buss:not(:checked) ~ #bon {
      display: none;
      }
</style>
  <section class="form-box" >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 form-wizard">
     
      <!-- Form Wizard -->
                     <form role="form" action="" method="post">

       <!-- Form progress -->
                      <div class="form-wizard-steps form-wizard-tolal-steps-3">
                       <div class="form-wizard-progress">
                           <div class="form-wizard-progress-line" data-now-value="12.25" data-number-of-steps="4" style="width: 12.25%;"></div>
                       </div>
        <!-- Step 1 -->
                       <div class="form-wizard-step active">
                        <div class="form-wizard-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        <p>Step 1</p>
                       </div>
        <!-- Step 1 -->
        
        <!-- Step 2 -->
                       <div class="form-wizard-step">
                        <div class="form-wizard-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        <p>Step 2</p>
                       </div>
        <!-- Step 2 -->
        
        <!-- Step 3 -->
        <div class="form-wizard-step">
                        <div class="form-wizard-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        <p>Step 3</p>
                       </div>
        <!-- Step 3 -->
                      </div>
       <!-- Form progress -->
                      
       
       <!-- Form Step 1 -->
                      <fieldset>
       <label >Click to hide or show content on step2</label>
                           <input style="margin-left:20px;" type="radio" id="cuss" name="sh" value="con" />
                           <label style="padding-right:10px;">Show</label>
                           <input type="radio" id="hid" name="sh" value="hid" />
                           <label>Hide</label>

                                <div class="form-wizard-buttons">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
       <!-- Form Step 1 -->

       <!-- Form Step 2 -->
                            <fieldset>
                              <div id="con" class="form-group">
         <p>Content to show or hide depend on the checkbox</p>
         </div>
         
        
                                <div class="form-wizard-buttons">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
       <!-- Form Step 2 -->
       
       <!-- Form Step 3 -->
       <fieldset>
        <label >Click to hide or show</label>
                           <input style="margin-left:20px;" type="radio" id="buss" name="sh" value="con" />
                           <label style="padding-right:10px;">Show</label>
                           <input type="radio" id="hid" name="sh" value="hid" />
                           <label>Hide</label>
         <div id="bon" class="form-group">
         <p>Content to show or hide depend on the checkbox</p>
         </div>
                                <div class="form-wizard-buttons">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
       <!-- Form Step 3->
                     </form>
      <!-- Form Wizard -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add an event when clicking the show or hide option.
I added a new section to your JavaScript ("Content Toggle"), and added 2 classes for the elements which you can click.

Now when clicking one of each radio buttons, content on step 2 will be either shown or hidden.

If you want to toggle step2 with clicking radio buttons on step3, you can simply add the classes ("js-show-con" and "js-hide-con") to the input fields there.

```js
"use strict";
function scroll_to_class(element_class, removed_height) {
 var scroll_to = $(element_class).offset().top - removed_height;
 if($(window).scrollTop() != scroll_to) {
  $('.form-wizard').stop().animate({scrollTop: scroll_to}, 0);
 }
}

function bar_progress(progress_line_object, direction) {
 var number_of_steps = progress_line_object.data('number-of-steps');
 var now_value = progress_line_object.data('now-value');
 var new_value = 0;
 if(direction == 'right') {
  new_value = now_value + ( 100 / number_of_steps );
 }
 else if(direction == 'left') {
  new_value = now_value - ( 100 / number_of_steps );
 }
 progress_line_object.attr('style', 'width: ' + new_value + '%;').data('now-value', new_value);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  /**
   * Content Toggle
   */
  var conElement = $('#con');
  var showElement = $('.js-show-con');
  var hideElement = $('.js-hide-con');

  showElement.click(
    function() {
      conElement.show()
    }
  );

  hideElement.click(
    function() {
      conElement.hide()
    }
  );
    
    /*
        Form
    */
    $('.form-wizard fieldset:first').fadeIn('slow');
    
    $('.form-wizard .required').on('focus', function() {
     $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    });
    
    // next step
    $('.form-wizard .btn-next').on('click', function() {
     var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
     var next_step = true;
     // navigation steps / progress steps
     var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-step.active');
     var progress_line = $(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-progress-line');
     
     // fields validation
     parent_fieldset.find('.required').each(function() {
      if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
       $(this).addClass('input-error');
       next_step = false;
      }
      else {
       $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }
     });
     // fields validation
     
     if( next_step ) {
      parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
       // change icons
       current_active_step.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active');
       // progress bar
       bar_progress(progress_line, 'right');
       // show next step
       $(this).next().fadeIn();
       // scroll window to beginning of the form
       scroll_to_class( $('.form-wizard'), 20 );
      });
     }
     
    });
    
    // previous step
    $('.form-wizard .btn-previous').on('click', function() {
     // navigation steps / progress steps
     var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-step.active');
     var progress_line = $(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-progress-line');
     
     $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function() {
      // change icons
      current_active_step.removeClass('active').prev().removeClass('activated').addClass('active');
      // progress bar
      bar_progress(progress_line, 'left');
      // show previous step
      $(this).prev().fadeIn();
      // scroll window to beginning of the form
   scroll_to_class( $('.form-wizard'), 20 );
     });
    });
    
    // submit
    $('.form-wizard').on('submit', function(e) {
     
     // fields validation
     $(this).find('.required').each(function() {
      if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).addClass('input-error');
      }
      else {
       $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }
     });
     // fields validation
     
    });
    
    
});





// image uploader scripts 

var $dropzone = $('.image_picker'),
    $droptarget = $('.drop_target'),
    $dropinput = $('#inputFile'),
    $dropimg = $('.image_preview'),
    $remover = $('[data-action="remove_current_image"]');

$dropzone.on('dragover', function() {
  $droptarget.addClass('dropping');
  return false;
});

$dropzone.on('dragend dragleave', function() {
  $droptarget.removeClass('dropping');
  return false;
});

$dropzone.on('drop', function(e) {
  $droptarget.removeClass('dropping');
  $droptarget.addClass('dropped');
  $remover.removeClass('disabled');
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0],
      reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    $dropimg.css('background-image', 'url(' + event.target.result + ')');
  };
  
  console.log(file);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  return false;
});

$dropinput.change(function(e) {
  $droptarget.addClass('dropped');
  $remover.removeClass('disabled');
  $('.image_title input').val('');
  
  var file = $dropinput.get(0).files[0],
      reader = new FileReader();
  
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    $dropimg.css('background-image', 'url(' + event.target.result + ')');
  }
  
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

$remover.on('click', function() {
  $dropimg.css('background-image', '');
  $droptarget.removeClass('dropped');
  $remover.addClass('disabled');
  $('.image_title input').val('');
});

$('.image_title input').blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $droptarget.removeClass('dropped');
  }
});

// image uploader scripts
```

```css
.form-box {
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 
 background: rgb(234,88,4); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(234,88,4,1) 0%, rgba(234,40,3,1) 51%, rgba(234,88,4,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(234,88,4,1) 0%,rgba(234,40,3,1) 51%,rgba(234,88,4,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(234,88,4,1) 0%,rgba(234,40,3,1) 51%,rgba(234,88,4,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ea5804', endColorstr='#ea5804',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.form-wizard {
 padding: 25px; 
 background: #fff;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 3px #777;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #888;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
 
.form-wizard strong { font-weight: 500; }

.form-wizard a, .form-wizard a:hover, .form-wizard a:focus {
 color: #ea2803;
 text-decoration: none;
    -o-transition: all .3s; -moz-transition: all .3s; -webkit-transition: all .3s; -ms-transition: all .3s; transition: all .3s;
}

.form-wizard h1, .form-wizard h2 {
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.form-wizard h3 {
 font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #ea2803;
    line-height: 30px;
 margin-top: 0; 
 margin-bottom: 5px; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.form-wizard h4 {
 float:left;
 font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #ea2803;
    line-height: 26px;
 width:100%;
}
.form-wizard h4  span{
 float:right;
 font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.form-wizard table tr th{font-weight:normal;}

.form-wizard img { max-width: 100%; }

.form-wizard ::-moz-selection { background: #ea2803; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
.form-wizard ::selection { background: #ea2803; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }


.form-control {
 height: 44px;
 width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 44px;
    color: #888;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;
    -o-transition: all .3s; -moz-transition: all .3s; -webkit-transition: all .3s; -ms-transition: all .3s; transition: all .3s;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"], .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"], .radio input[type="radio"], .radio-inline input[type="radio"] {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 9px;
 margin-left: -20px;
}

.form-control option:hover, .form-control option:checked  {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #ea2803 inset;
}

.form-control:focus {
 outline: 0;
 background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;
}

.form-control:-moz-placeholder { color: #888; }
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #888; }
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #888; }

.form-wizard label { font-weight: 300; }
.form-wizard label span { color:#ea2803; }


.form-wizard .btn {
 min-width: 105px;
 height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;
    -o-transition: all .3s; -moz-transition: all .3s; -webkit-transition: all .3s; -ms-transition: all .3s; transition: all .3s;
}

.form-wizard .btn:hover {
 background:#f34727; 
 color: #fff; 
 }
.form-wizard .btn:active { 
 outline: 0; 
 background:#f34727; 
 color: #fff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: none; 
 -webkit-box-shadow: none; 
 box-shadow: none; 
 }
.form-wizard .btn:focus,
.form-wizard .btn:active:focus,
.form-wizard .btn.active:focus { 
 outline: 0; 
 background:#f34727; 
 color: #fff; 
}

.form-wizard .btn.btn-next,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-next:focus,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-next:active:focus, 
.form-wizard .btn.btn-next.active:focus { 
background: #ea2803; 
}

.form-wizard .btn.btn-submit,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-submit:focus,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-submit:active:focus, 
.form-wizard .btn.btn-submit.active:focus { 
background: #ea2803; 
}

.form-wizard .btn.btn-previous,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-previous:focus,
.form-wizard .btn.btn-previous:active:focus, 
.form-wizard .btn.btn-previous.active:focus { 
background: #bbb;
}

.form-wizard .success h3{
 color: #4F8A10;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px auto !important;
}
.form-wizard .success .success-icon {
 color: #4F8A10;
 font-size: 100px;
 border: 5px solid #4F8A10;
 border-radius: 100px;
 text-align: center !important;
 width: 110px;
 margin: 25px auto;
}
.form-wizard .progress-bar {
 background-color: #ea2803;
}

.form-wizard-steps{ 
 margin:auto; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative; 
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.form-wizard-step{
 padding-top:10px !important;
 border:2px solid #fff;
 background:#ccc;
 -ms-transform: skewX(-30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-30deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(-30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
.form-wizard-step.active{
 background:#ea2803;
}
.form-wizard-step.activated{
 background:#ea2803;
}
.form-wizard-progress { 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 36px;
 left: 0; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 0px; 
 background: #ea2803;
}
.form-wizard-progress-line { 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 height: 0px; 
 background: #ea2803; 
}

.form-wizard-tolal-steps-3 .form-wizard-step { 
 position: relative;
 float: left; 
 width: 33.33%; 
 padding: 0 5px; 
}
.form-wizard-tolal-steps-4 .form-wizard-step { 
 position: relative; 
 float: left; 
 width: 25%; 
 padding: 0 5px; 
}
.form-wizard-tolal-steps-5 .form-wizard-step { 
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 padding: 0 5px;
}

.form-wizard-step-icon {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 40px; 
 height: 40px; 
 margin-top: 4px; 
 background: #ddd;
 font-size: 16px; 
 color: #777; 
 line-height: 40px;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
 border-radius: 50%;
 -ms-transform: skewX(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(30deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
.form-wizard-step.activated .form-wizard-step-icon {
 background: #ea2803; 
 border: 1px solid #fff; 
 color: #fff; 
 line-height: 38px;
}
.form-wizard-step.active .form-wizard-step-icon {
 background: #fff; 
 border: 1px solid #fff; 
 color: #ea2803; 
 line-height: 38px;
}

.form-wizard-step p { 
 color: #fff;
 -ms-transform: skewX(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(30deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
.form-wizard-step.activated p { color: #fff; }
.form-wizard-step.active p { color: #fff; }

.form-wizard fieldset { 
 display: none; 
 text-align: left; 
 border:0px !important
}

.form-wizard-buttons { text-align: right; }

.form-wizard .input-error { border-color: #ea2803;}

/** image uploader **/
.image-upload a[data-action] {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}
.image-upload a[data-action] i {
  width: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
}
.image-upload a[data-action]:hover {
  color: #ea2803;
}
.image-upload a[data-action].disabled {
  opacity: 0.35;
  cursor: default;
}
.image-upload a[data-action].disabled:hover {
  color: #555;
}
.settings_wrap{
 margin-top:20px;
}
.image_picker .settings_wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.image_picker .settings_wrap .drop_target,
.image_picker .settings_wrap .settings_actions {
  float: left;
}
.image_picker .settings_wrap .drop_target {
  margin-right: 18px;
}
.image_picker .settings_wrap .settings_actions {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.settings_actions.vertical a {
  display: block;
}
.drop_target {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.2s;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 8px solid #E0E0E0;
}
.drop_target input[type="file"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.drop_target::before {
 content: 'Drop Hear';
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 220px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 transition: color 0.2s;
}
.drop_target:hover,
.drop_target.dropping {
  background: #f80;
  border-top-color: #cc6d00;
}
.drop_target:hover:before,
.drop_target.dropping:before {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.drop_target .image_preview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>

</head>

<body>
<style>
#cuss:not(:checked) ~ #con {
      display: none;
      }

#buss:not(:checked) ~ #bon {
      display: none;
      }
</style>
  <section class="form-box" >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 form-wizard">

      <!-- Form Wizard -->
                     <form role="form" action="" method="post">

       <!-- Form progress -->
                      <div class="form-wizard-steps form-wizard-tolal-steps-3">
                       <div class="form-wizard-progress">
                           <div class="form-wizard-progress-line" data-now-value="12.25" data-number-of-steps="4" style="width: 12.25%;"></div>
                       </div>
        <!-- Step 1 -->
                       <div class="form-wizard-step active">
                        <div class="form-wizard-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        <p>Step 1</p>
                       </div>
        <!-- Step 1 -->

        <!-- Step 2 -->
                       <div class="form-wizard-step">
                        <div class="form-wizard-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        <p>Step 2</p>
                       </div>
        <!-- Step 2 -->

        <!-- Step 3 -->
        <div class="form-wizard-step">
                        <div class="form-wizard-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        <p>Step 3</p>
                       </div>
        <!-- Step 3 -->
                      </div>
       <!-- Form progress -->


       <!-- Form Step 1 -->
                      <fieldset>
       <label >Click to hide or show content on step2</label>
                           <input class="js-show-con" style="margin-left:20px;" type="radio" id="cuss" name="sh" value="con" />
                           <label style="padding-right:10px;">Show</label>
                           <input class="js-hide-con" type="radio" id="hid" name="sh" value="hid" />
                           <label>Hide</label>

                                <div class="form-wizard-buttons">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
       <!-- Form Step 1 -->

       <!-- Form Step 2 -->
                            <fieldset>
                              <div id="con" class="form-group">
         <p>Content to show or hide depend on the checkbox</p>
         </div>


                                <div class="form-wizard-buttons">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
       <!-- Form Step 2 -->

       <!-- Form Step 3 -->
       <fieldset>
        <label >Click to hide or show</label>
                           <input style="margin-left:20px;" type="radio" id="buss" name="sh" value="con" />
                           <label style="padding-right:10px;">Show</label>
                           <input type="radio" id="hid" name="sh" value="hid" />
                           <label>Hide</label>
         <div id="bon" class="form-group">
         <p>Content to show or hide depend on the checkbox</p>
         </div>
                                <div class="form-wizard-buttons">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
       <!-- Form Step 3->
                     </form>
      <!-- Form Wizard -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</body>
</html>
```